# TemplateColumn doesn't diplay the Header in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made in my DataGrid a TemplateColumn with this structure:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Squadra" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStringFormat="Squadra">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <Image MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" Source="{Binding Path= 'crestUrl' , Converter={StaticResource NameToImageConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" />
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But the Header "Squadra" insn't visible when I start my solution, also if I populate the DataGrid through code the Header became visible. Is this a bug of WPF or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it 's because your column is visible but with a `width` of `0` (`SizeToCells` and no content).

Set a `MinWidth="150"`